# Expression is not assignable, coordinate attribute from MKAnnotation class delegate

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, mkannotation

I did this schema in order to explain better what is my troubles.

[image]

So, what can I do to fix it? Thank you =)

Comment: It seems that `puntoXML` is readonly.

Comment: What is `puntoXML`?  what is `valor`?

Comment: As the pic says: `puntoXML is MapAnnotation` type and is `(nonatomic, assign)` so is not readonly, then `valor is string from parser method`.

Comment: @rokimoki Sorry I don't see where it says `puntoXML` is of type `MapAnnotation`?

Comment: @trojanfoe: in 3rd last line of image :D

Comment: You can't assign `struct` values of a property. See rmaddy's answer. Unrelated, given that your `Annotation` has a `@property` for `coordinate`, you should _not_ also define an instance variable for that. Get rid of the instance variable. The same is true for `title`, `subtitle`, and `imgName` of `MapAnnotation`. Let the compiler synthesize those for you.

Comment: +1 for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is a `struct`, i.e. a value type. It is passed around by value, which is another way of saying "copying". If you assign its fields (e.g. longitude) all that would do is modifying a *copy*; the original `coordinate` inside your `Annotation` would remain intact. That is why the property is not assignable.

To fix this, you should add separate properties for latitude and longitude, and use them instead:

```
@interface Annotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation>
    @property (readwrite) CLLocationDegrees latitude;
    @property (readwrite) CLLocationDegrees longitude;
    @property (nonatomic,assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    ...
@end

@implementation Annotation
    -(CLLocationDegrees) latitude {
        return _coordinate.latitude;
    }
    -(void)setLatitude:(CLLocationDegrees)val {
        _coordinate.latitude = val;
    }
    -(CLLocationDegrees) longitude{
        return _coordinate.longitude;
    }
    -(void)setLongitude:(CLLocationDegrees)val {
        _coordinate.longitude = val;
    }
@end
```

Now your XML parser code can do this:

```
if ([llave isEqualTo:@"lat"]) {
    puntoXML.latitude = [valor doubleValue];
} else if ([llave isEqualTo:@"lon"]) {
    puntoXML.longitude = [valor doubleValue];
} ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems to be working 100% at least no compiler errors, I know about curly braces but its not required to be an struct, right?

Comment: @rokimoki That was actually a syntax error which I fixed now. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
puntoXML.coordinate.latitude = [valor floatValue];
```

to:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = puntoXML.coordinate;
coord.latitude = [valor floatValue];
puntoXML.coordinate = coord;
```

Make a similar change for the `longitude`. Also note that you will need to add curly braces to the `if` statements.

Comment: Nice answer, once I asked similar kind of question and got many downvotes :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952680/why-there-is-no-api-to-directly-update-x-y-height-width . Still I could not find the reason. Shame!!!

Comment: Why I can do this indeed?:
`CLLocationCoordinate2D initialLocation;
 initialLocation.latitude = lati;
 initialLocation.longitude = longi;`
@AnoopVaidya sometimes I get downvotes, today it's friday and everyone is in a good mood

Comment: @rokimoki Yes, you can set both the latitude and longitude if you want.

Comment: @rokimoki: I am not in good mood. I need to go office even on weekend, 2mrw on saturday ;(

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are assigning a copy of `CLLocationCoordinate2D` with your latitude/longitude.

`puntoXML.coorinate` returns a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` (a copy) so assigning `latitude` will have no effect.

Instead you need to create a complete `CLLocationCoordinate2D` with the new latitude and longitude and set that in one go.

**EDIT** better still provide separate properties for the latitude/longitude and provide a custom setter for each that sets their value in the `coordinate` instance variable.