# MKPointAnnotation Expression is not assignable

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkannotation

So I have the following code block, which is supposed to iterate over an array of JSON objects and place MKPointAnnotations on a map:

```
for(id jsonObject in dataArray)
{
    NSLog(@"%d",[dataArray count]);

    NSDictionary* jsonDictionary = jsonObject;

    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    NSString *lat = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"latitude"];
    NSString *lon = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"longitude"];

    point.coordinate.latitude = [lat doubleValue];
    point.coordinate.longitude = [lon doubleValue];

    [map addAnnotation:point];


}
```

However, the two lines:

```
    point.coordinate.latitude = [lat doubleValue];
    point.coordinate.longitude = [lon doubleValue];
```

are giving me an "Expression is not Assignable" error.  I can't for the life of me figure it out.  I've tried to make a CLLocationCoordinate2D object and assigning that, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2d coordinate = ...
MKPointAnnotation* annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotation.coordinate = coordinate;
[mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

It works in an existing app, just checked the code and the app.
Check this answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15162092/1032151

Comment: I just tried CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [[CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lat doubleValue], [lon doubleValue])]]; and it tells me: Parse Issue: Expected Identifier

Comment: CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lat doubleValue], [lon doubleValue]);